# Toad + oracle + hexadecimal 4,1XXXXXXXX52E15(41XXXXXXXX5198)

Tags: oracle

Actualmente al ejecutar el siguiente query:

```
SELECT
     SOL_RDDDETALLEREPROGRAMACION.operacion
  FROM evaluacion.SOL_RDDDETALLEREPROGRAMACION, 
       CREDITO.PRODUCTO P, 
       CREDITO.CUOTA C,
       CREDITO.CREDITO CA
  WHERE SOL_RDDDETALLEREPROGRAMACION.solicitud = 12345678 AND
        CA.credito(+) = SOL_RDDDETALLEREPROGRAMACION.operacion AND                        
        P.codigo (+) = SOL_RDDDETALLEREPROGRAMACION.subproducto AND
        C.credito (+) = SOL_RDDDETALLEREPROGRAMACION.operacion AND
        C.estado (+) < 0;
```

El campo OPERACION viene con el formato hexadecimal: 4,1XXXXXXXX52E15. tema que se soluciona al cambiar la linea `SOL_RDDDETALLEREPROGRAMACION.operacion` a `TO_CHAR(SOL_RDDDETALLEREPROGRAMACION.operacion)`.

La pregunta es, si existe otra manera que no sea agregar un `TO_CHAR`.

Comment: Al decir "viene con el formato" a donde te refieres que muestra dicho formato? En tu Herramienta de gestión de Base de Datos? En tu aplicación? Sé mas específico por favor para poder apoyarte en tu problema.

Comment: En el TOAD se visualiza de esta manera y posteriormente en la aplicación lo deja redondeado 41XXXXXXX4455200.

Comment: Debes ajustar en el formato de salida de TOAD, la mascara de como quieres visualizar la información numérica

Comment: Mike, el tema esta en que al consultar este valor en la aplicación, viene redondeado. Debería ser 55198 en ves de 55200.

Comment: Cual es el lenguaje de tu aplicación? Java, PHP, Otro? Asegúrate de usar un tipo de dato que permita almacenar valores largos numéricos (Ej: long en Java)

Comment: Es en C y la variable es tipo double.